Can't use .sh file in appspec.yml hooks in ECS Fargate green/blue deployment
I have a CI/CD structure on AWS with CodePipeline, CodeBuild, CodeDeploy, TaskDefinition, ECR, ECS green/blue deployment. I used AWS Fargate as a ECS service. I have Laravel and React apps which have seperated CodePipelines with green/blue.
I need a functionality to update BASE_URL variable which exist in .env file of React app. It should be green.mybackapp.com when front app is in green environment (to make sure that everything works correctly with my last version of backend). But it should be automatically changed to blue.mybackapp.com after I reroute all traffic to production. I think that one way to do it is using appspec hooks. But ECS Fargate appspec hooks only accept Lambda function (due to this docs). And I am not sure that it's possible to update .env file from Lambda function.
That's the my appspec.yaml:
version: 0.0
Resources:
  - TargetService:
      Type: AWS::ECS::Service
      Properties:
        TaskDefinition: <TASK_DEFINITION>
        LoadBalancerInfo:
          ContainerName: "nginx"
          ContainerPort: 80
Hooks:
- AfterAllowTestTraffic: "scripts/AfterAllowTestTraffic.sh"
- BeforeAllowTraffic: "scripts/BeforeAllowTraffic.sh"

It doesn't work, because it only accept lambda function name, not .sh file which exist in source code. I can't find any article or issue which someone faced with this problem.
Need a solution to my problem, link, article or discussion where solved someone my problem.

You can use a shell file to do anything. You can write a script to manage this operation. You can use grep to change the text of your .env file or assign it to memory. At which point it can be sent to a script, assigned to a variable, or manipulated based on other conditionals.
I hope this helps. The only place shell scripts fall short are, to interact with third party services beyond your navigable system or network - and even then, shell scripts can trigger scripts that can.

As I mentioned in my post, I can't use shell file in hooks for ECS. It only accept Lambda function. My question is how can I use shell file in appspec hooks.
